# How can I prevent json data from hijackers when sending android to php server and vise versa

Tags: php, android, json

I am sending data from android app to php and get data from php to android app in json format. If anyone hit my url in browser address bar, they can able to see what data i can send from php to android app and vise versa. How can i hide or collapse data so that the user cannot understand and what data i am transfer, even though they can see in browser. Is there any way to do this. If yes, please any one provide the sample code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Encryption for it. check it<https://gist.github.com/bricef/2436364>.

Comment: Start by using HTTPS to encrypt on the wire.  You can minimize and obfuscate the data, but you can't prevent them from seeing text in the browser.

Comment: you can use encryption before sending the data and decrypt data after receiving from server

Comment: use token based http request for android as well as web.

Comment: Is any encryption and decryption built-in function available in both android and php? Also What is the use of Base64. Is Base64 helpful in my case?

Comment: Best practice to avoid an user seeing the data within the url is to use POST method instead of GET in an http request. :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php